# Cakephp 3.x Table Beforefind, unable to stop event

Tags: events, cakephp, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

Per the documentation on the website of CakePHP: (https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforefind) stopping the event or supplying a return value should stop the find operation.

I'm using the following code in the Beforefind:

```
$event->stopPropagation();
return false;
```

But this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

The docs need some fixing there, as there's various things wrong with it, returning data won't make any difference, as the return value is never used, also you can't really use the `beforeFind` event for configuring caching, it's limited to the point of it not being useful, as the event is only being triggered for non-cached queries, and for those it's triggered *after* the cache is being checked.

That being said, stopping the find operation *is* possible by providing custom results, not by returning data, but by setting it via `Query::setResult()`, which expects an instance of `\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface`.

An example would be:

```
$results = [];
$resultSet = new \Cake\Datasource\ResultSetDecorator($results);
$query->setResult($results);
$event->stopPropagation();
```

That would make the query return an empty result set (`ResultSetDecorator` is just a collection that implements `ResultSetInterface`), which is the closest you can come to "stopping" the query.